# Sorting in txt.file python

Tags: python, sorting

am assigned to sort and display Record of coaches hourly pay rate in ascending order from 0 Dollars to 500 Dollars, For example, I have 3 coaches the first coach hourly pay rate is 250 dollars the second is 140 dollars and the third is 320 dollars and those 3 coaches records are in one txt.file and not sorted

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide code example of what you have tried.

Comment: Example data will also be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a text file by three columns with a specific order to those columns in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726710/how-do-i-sort-a-text-file-by-three-columns-with-a-specific-order-to-those-column)

Comment: syntax will be like this: `lines.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], x[2], int(x[3])))` 
If you want descending order then place `-` like this `lines.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], -x[2], int(x[3])))` ===> `x[2] --> descending`